# Return statements with currying techniques

Tags: javascript, return, currying

While learning with FreeCodeCamp I'm faced with a question about currying.

The solution was this:

```
function add(x) {
// Add your code below this line
return function(y) {
  return function(z) {
    return x + y + z;
    }
  }
}
add(10)(20)(30);
```

However, I'm confused as to why the return statements here aren't terminating the execution of the function?

I was under the impression that as soon as you use a return statement, that line would be executed and everything beyond that would be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ends only the own function. The returned function isn't called yet.

```
function add(x) {
    return function(y) {      // \
        return function(z) {  //  |
            return x + y + z; //  | part of the returned function
        };                    //  |
    };                        // /
}

add(10)(20)(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes using `return` does end the functions execution, but the returned value is a function itself, that then gets called directly, the next function gets executed, ended with `return`ing another function, that then gets called directly again and produces the result.

```
add(10)(20)(30);

// evaluted to:
function(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return function(z) {
      return x + y + z;
    };
  };
}(10)(20)(30)

// evaluated to:
function(y) { // x = 10 through closure
   return function(z) {
     return x + y + z;
   };
}(20)(30);

// evaluated to
function(z) { // x = 10, y = 20 through closure
  return x + y + z;
}(30)

// evaluated to
60
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time it is returning a new function, its being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You would be right if one function had multiple return statements, but in this case, there are multiple functions (each with their own return statement). Two of the functions just happen to return another function.